# Is OData a viable option for a datasource

Tags: .net, entity-framework, odata

This is more of a theoretical question, I am not sure if it is the usual type of question, but maybe people will have answers for me.

Most of my solutions will have multiple projects. One or two "Main" applications, often web based, and then a few smaller ones, possibly command line apps that allow me to run certain commands, or import or export data, for various reasons.

I usually have one project that uses Entity Framework, as my main "Database connection", and the other projects then use reference that project.

I am wondering of creating an OData project, and putting that between the "EF project", and everything else would be a viable solution.
Are there pros, and cons to this implementation?

I would imagine that it might add a bit of overhead to what ever the "Main Web Application" in the solution would be, but for the other smaller ones, but would lighten up the "auxiliary" applications, especially if they are running on a few different computers.

I could do both, and have the web apps referencing the EF project, and everything else going making calls to the OData project, but then I lose the elegance of a single route for data to go through.

Comment: *Why* would you want to put anything in front of the database? How could it "lighten" anything when it adds yet another remote network call and deserialization on top of the database call?

Comment: I think you should read [Premature Scalability and the route of all evil](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/premature-scalability-and-the-root-of-all-evil/).

Comment: By Lighten, I meant the smaller apps won't need to know about Entity Framework, they could just make all the "DB Calls" over HTTP.

I am going to read that. Thank you.

Comment: Then use Dapper or another MicroORM. Or plain ADO.NET.  Calls over HTTP aren't "just", they are much heavier and slower than TDS. Besides, EF's job is to map entities to data. With OData you still have to map your entities to data

Comment: Yes, I would use OData with EF. Was just thinking of OData as the "in between".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I want to close this question off. The question was a speculation, and I think you did answer it.
Could you make your answer and _answer_, so I can select it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Do you want to create an answer for this (even "don't do it", it should I close the question?